# Javascript object loses type inside array

Tags: javascript

```
    /* Game */
    function Game() {
        return {
            items: []
        }
    }

    /* Item */
    function Item(id, name, description, image, price) {
        return {
            getId: function () {
                return id;
            }
        }
    }

    Item.prototype.toString = function() {
        return id + ":" + name;
    };

    /* Logic.. */
    var game = new Game();
    var sword = new Item(1, "Sword", "An iron sword", "sword.png", 10);
    game.items.push(sword);


    console.log(game.items[0] instanceof Item); // false
    console.log(typeof game.items[0]);          // object
    console.log(game.items[0]);                 // Object{}
```

I have a feeling that because my custom objects go into an array that they lose their 'custom type', in this case `Item`, when I pull them out.
How can I keep a list of `Item` and have Javascript find out its real type?

Comment: Array is a red herring. You are retuning object from constructor. That has some interesting behavior (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2522-providing-a-return-value-in-a-javascript-constructor.htm), but generally if your constructor function returns object, it is used. If it returns primitive, reference to newly constructed object is used. See specification http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_13.2.2 , point 9 and 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor functions return plain objects. Constructor functions can do this, but IMO shouldn't do this.

You can change your constructor like this:

```
/* Game */
function Game() {
    this.items = [];
}

/* Item */
function Item(id, name, description, image, price) {
    this.id = id;
}

// this is very uncommon in JavaScript, looks more like Java
Item.prototype.getId = function () {
    return this.id;
};

Item.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.id + ":" + this.name;
};
```

Now it should work like you expect.

Not directly related to this problem, just a hint (because I remarked that defining `getId` is very uncommon in JavaScript);

In modern JavaScript you don't have to define explicit get/set functions. Instead you typically access the property directly (like a public member in Java). In case you have to apply some logic when the property is accessed (read/write), you can define a function which will be called transparently (see [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)):

```
Object.defineProperty(Item.prototype, 'id', {
    get: function () {
        return this.id;
    },
    set: function (value) {
        if (!isNaN(value)) { // just an example to add some logic
            throw Error('Item.id must be a number!');
        }
        this.id = value;
    }
});
```

Comment: I see. But the inner return object gives you the ability for private properties. It appears I need to revise my idea. As far as the getId, I wanted a function to test with and figured ID was mandatory for my data structure..

Comment: OK. So you wanted to hide private members. That's not easy with objects. Have a look at [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) and [JavaScript Patterns Collection](http://shichuan.github.io/javascript-patterns/). Often the simplest way to do it is with a naming convention, e.g. members beginning with '_' should be treated privately. Can be enforced with [JSDoc @private tag](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-private.html).